# How to log info using NLog in Xamarin forms project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nlog, audit-logging

I am using Nlog to log exceptions in my project(cross platform xamarin project).

My implementation:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Trace(string text, params object[] args);
    void Debug(string text, params object[] args);
    void Info(string text, params object[] args);
    void Warn(string text, params object[] args);
    void Error(string text, params object[] args);
    void Fatal(string text, params object[] args);
}

public interface ILogManager
{
    ILogger GetLog([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath]string callerFilePath = "");
}
```

In Platform specific UWP project I have created 2 classes:

```
public class NLogLogger : ILogger
{
    private Logger log;

    public NLogLogger(Logger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public void Debug(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Debug(text, args);
    }

    public void Error(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Error(text, args);
    }

    public void Fatal(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Fatal(text, args);
    }

    public void Info(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Info(text, args);
    }

    public void Trace(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Trace(text, args);
    }

    public void Warn(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        log.Warn(text, args);
    }

}
```

NLogManager Class:

```
  public class NLogManager : ILogManager
  {
    public NLogManager()
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget();
        config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

        var consoleRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(consoleRule);

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        string folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        string fileNameWithDate = "Log_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMddyyyy") + ".txt";
        fileTarget.FileName = Path.Combine(folder, fileNameWithDate);
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Warn, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(fileRule);

        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }

    public EverwellUnpluggedLogger.ILogger GetLog([CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "")
    {
        string fileName = callerFilePath;

         if (fileName.Contains("/"))
           {
               fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) + 1);
           }

           var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(fileName);
           return new NLogLogger(logger);
    }
}
```

If exception is thrown in any method I am using below line to record it in text file. This works fine.

```
ILogger logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog();
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
```

Similarly when when I am using logger.info(), this does not record anything in my text file.

```
 logger.Info(logs);
```

Is there a need to change any configuration in Nlog.config file?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you question is why this line doesn't log to fileTarget:

```
logger.Info(logs);
```

Then the issue is probably that you only include warnings (or worse):

```
var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Warn, fileTarget);
```

Try changing to this instead:

```
var fileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, fileTarget);
```